# Showing results n times from user input n

Tags: c, for-loop

I wish to get a user input of a integer(n) and print my output `hi` for n times.

The codes I wrote is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("input the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf("hi");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this code in `gcc`, I get a compile error:

> mycode.c:5:16: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
> scanf("%d", &i);
> ^ mycode.c:5:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in mycode.c:6:21:
> error: ‘n’ undeclared (first use in this function)    for (int i = 0;
> i<n; i++)

How can I fix my codes to output `hi` n times?

Comment: It does not appear that you ever assign `n`

Comment: `i` must be declared before the first use.

Comment: Remember, in C, the compiler reads the file in 1-pass, so before you use `i` in your code, you must declare it. Here, you have two problems (1) `i` isn't declared before `scanf()` and (2) your loop also uses the variable `i` -- which will *shadow* any declaration of `i` above `scanf()` (choose another variable name). Last, you cannot use any user-input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to determine if the input succeeded or failed. E.g. `if (scanf ("%d", &i) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`

Comment: While things like indentation doesn't matter for the compiler, it matters for people trying to read and understand your code. It will also help you understand your own code as it becomes more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error is telling you that `i` is not defined.  This is quite obviously because the line containing that error message occurs *before* the line where `i` is defined.  I think you meant to read the value `n`, since your `i` loop wants that.  And you also haven't defined `n`, which is what the other error tells you.

So, here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0;                      //<-- You need to define n
    printf("input the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);                //<-- You need to read into n
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("hi");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have indented your code, and that it is now easier to read.  Please learn from this, and do it yourself *always* when writing code.